# Find lines without asterisk after colon

Tags: python

In these examples I want it to search if after the first ":" ( colon ) there is a "*" ( asterisk )

```
pepe1:*:19550:0:97799:7:::
pedro_891:*:19420::::::
jose:holawuenas:7:::
enrique:*:19762:0:97799:7:::
```

*(It's all invented, no real information is shown)*

Once I find this pattern I want it to only show me on the screen the lines that do not meet this pattern

Something like this:

> The only line that does not match the pattern is:
> `jose:holawuenas:7:::`

This last one does not worry me because I know how to do it, only the pattern fails me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line appears to have 8 colons except the one you want to catch.

```
for line in data:
  parts = line.split(':')
  if not (len(parts) == 9 and parts[1] == '*'):
    raise ValueError()
```

Note: `/etc/passwd` files only have 7 fields

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re

lines = [
    "pepe1:*:19550:0:97799:7:::",
    "pedro_891:*:19420::::::",
    "jose:holawuenas:7:::",
    "enrique:*:19762:0:97799:7:::"
]

pattern = r"^\w+:\*"

for line in lines:
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if not match:
        print("The only line that does not match the pattern is:", line)
```

Comment: You may want to anchor that more specifically, like `"^\w+:\*"`

Comment: @tadman You are right. I did. Thanks

Comment: `print(*(f"The only line that does not match the pattern is: {line}" for line in lines if not re.search(pattern, line)), sep='\n')`